# Settings sidebars does not fit

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

I am trying to make static stripes on both sides of a browser where page content flows within. I am using Bootstrap. I have spared one cell on the left and one cell on the right for static content. These cells contain another  which goes all along the page but 50% width of the container cell.

My code is as follows :

```
<div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1">
        <div style="background-image: url(./Content/images/strip_left.jpg); background-repeat: repeat-y; width: 20%; float: left; min-height:100%; position:fixed; top:0px; bottom:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-1">
    <!-- This is where the page content flows -->
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1" style="float:right; margin:0px; right:0px; text-align:right;">
        <div style="background-image: url(./Content/images/strip_right.jpg); background-repeat: repeat-y; width: 20%; float: right; min-height:100%; position:fixed; top:0px; bottom:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that I am getting the following : 
[image: Page layout]

Left side is OK. But I haven't been able to close the gap on the right. float, margin, padding did not work. How can I fix this issue?

P.S. : Green areas are the leftmost and rightmost divs. Yellow area is the content area. White region is here I set the background image as stripe.

Comment: Consider using pull-right and pull-left Bootstrap classes instead of an inline css for the float/alignment

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running into issues using both the float and fixed position.

```
position: fixed; /* use this only if you want the element fixed positioned in relation to the window */
```

Here's a simplified fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ro5hvwub/2

Is this what you are looking for?